# Django model with many ownership

Tags: django, django-models

I have write this model:

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=255,)
    owners = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

I would like to add current user into owners field on save.
I don't want declare this in a form but in model, overriding save method. As follow:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.owners = request.user
    super(Customer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

but obviously request doesn't exist...
what I can define this in model?

Comment: You don't. Models (should) be request-unaware. You do that in the corresponding view.

Comment: i need add new customer from Django Admin and from front-end, I would like to avoid repeat code

Comment: but the entire idea of a model-view-controller pattern is that the models are request unaware. In fact there is not per se a request. Management commands for example or cronjobs have no request, since these are triggered through the process, not through a HTTP request, and these have definitely not a user.

Comment: so I have to repeat the modeling both in admin and in form?

Comment: not in the form, since a form is also, by default, request unaware. By the view. You can, if you really want to, encapsulate the logic in a function, and call that function in both the view, and the `ModelAdmin.save_model`.